# Best way to backup (automatically, cron) google drive docs

Tags: google-drive-api, backup

I have a google drive for my company, and I would like to backup all theses data (mainly documents...) every days (in case of sb would delete them accidentally)... Is there an easy solution to do that ? I mean to copy all theses data, automatically to another google drive account or to my local disc ?

Thanks you,

Comment: question is not about programming, thus offtopic to this forum

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Multcloud](https://www.multcloud.com/home). This website allow to manage all your cloud spaces together. You can add your company's drive a/c and other drive a/c or dropbox or anything, then sync company a/c with the a/c that you want.

Comment: Nice, tks you, maybe a free solution exists ? (cron feature is premuim in multcloud)

Comment: you can use the sync, feature its free.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Google Drive has to offer.

**[Install Google Drive on your Mac or PC](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2490101?hl=en)**

> Automatically sync Google Drive files on your computer with your
>   Google Drive files on the web using "Google Drive for your Mac/PC."
>   You can do things like:
>
> - Drag files in and out of folders
> - Edit, save, and remove files
>
> Any changes you make locally in your Google Drive folder will sync to
>   your "My Drive" on the web. That means if you share, move, edit, or
>   move files to trash, your changes will also show in My Drive the next
>   time your computer syncs.

Comment: HI, I already know that, but the problem is that I am working with 30 others persons on this drive... So if sb remove accidentally some files, I need to recover them with a backup solution. so I want to sync theses files to ANOTHER drive account. It should generate one archive by day...qnd back it up